# jQuery, remove text from the last child

Tags: jquery

I have the following breadcrumb set up, how would I go about removing the last » in the list item...

Here's my code to adding in the, » but I would like to also remove it from the last item in the list.

```
 $(".breadCrumbs li").append(" &raquo; ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RqWYq/

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about not appending >> for the last li

```
$(".breadCrumbs li:not(:last)").append(" &raquo; ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RqWYq/1/

Answer (score 4):

I would instead not add it to the last li. http://jsfiddle.net/RqWYq/2/

```
$(".breadCrumbs li").not(":last-child").append(" &raquo; ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$(".breadCrumbs li:not(:last-child)").append(" &raquo; ");
```